# adding a button to Gmail contact hover widget in the website

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I don't know if this possible, 
I wanted to add a button with custom action using email address to the hover widget that comes up.
I'm assuming google app script should be the right way to go. But don't know what to search in the reference guide.

[image: from gmail]

Comment: You cannot modify the Gmail UI, only your add-on's cards.

Comment: @tehhowch thats exactly what I thought but wanted to ask before giving up on it.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail add-ons can't modify the Gmail UI, they only could create Cards which are shown on side panel.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/